# Intermittent Web Sockets error with Apache reverse proxy

Tags: websocket, apache2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have Apache set up to reverse-proxy web socket requests to a JVM server. Sometimes they work. Sometimes (rarely, but sometimes) they don't work. This has the hallmarks of a heisenbug.

The client:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com/socket/xyz");
socket.onmessage = function(item) {});
```

Sometimes this works. Sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't I get the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/websocket' failed:
Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
```

**This always works when the Chrome debug console is open. It sometimes fails when it isn't.**

My Apache config is minimal:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName      example.com
  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  ErrorLog         /var/log/apache2/example
  TransferLog      /var/log/apache2/example
  UseCanonicalName On

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass        /socket/ ws://upstream.host/socket/
  ProxyPassReverse /socket/ ws://upstream.host/socket/
  ProxyPass        / http://upstream.host/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://upstream.host/
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So **I can't go into the network inspector and see what happened**. Short of getting Wireshark involved, I'm a bit stuck.

I can't see any errors in my Apache error log.

I can't see any errors in my application log.

My only thought is that somehow there's some kind of race condition that the Chrone developer console is preventing, but I can't think what.

I'm using the [HTTP-Kit](http://www.http-kit.org/) library on the server and React.js on the client. I imagine that it's `proxy_wstunnel` doing the work in Apache2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same troubles with the proxy pass module from Apache (v2.4.6), three, four connections at the same time works as expected, however with many request a few times per second failed. Seems like the module is still a little buggy.

Maybe not a direct solution to your problem, but I switched to [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) and everything is working flawless now.

Comment: I find that have some bug in proxy_wstunnel_module, in my case using mod_cluster with EnableWsTunnel has the same behaviour mentioned.